# Sorting array by 2 conditions in Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, object

I want to sort an array of objects by both id and name. First it should be sorted by id in ascending order. Then it should be sorted by name in ascending order.

Sort function

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var list = [{
      "id": "ts1",
      "name": "TS1"
    }, {
      "id": "ts10",
      "name": "TS10"
    }, {
      "id": "ts11",
      "name": "TS11"
    }, {
      "id": "ts12",
      "name": "TS12"
    }, {
      "id": "ts13",
      "name": "TS2"
    }, {
      "id": "ts13",
      "name": "TS1"
    }, {
      "id": "ts13",
      "name": "TS3"
    }, {
      "id": "ts14",
      "name": "TS14"
    }, {
      "id": "ts15",
      "name": "TS15"
    }, {
      "id": "ts16",
      "name": "TS16"
    }, {
      "id": "ts17",
      "name": "TS17"
    }, {
      "id": "ts18",
      "name": "TS18"
    }, {
      "id": "ts19",
      "name": "TS19"
    }, {
      "id": "ts2",
      "name": "TS2"
    }, {
      "id": "ts20",
      "name": "TS20"
    }, {
      "id": "ts21",
      "name": "TS21"
    }, {
      "id": "ts22",
      "name": "TS22"
    }, {
      "id": "ts3",
      "name": "TS3"
    }, {
      "id": "ts4",
      "name": "TS4"
    }, {
      "id": "ts5",
      "name": "TS5"
    }, {
      "id": "ts6",
      "name": "TS6"
    }, {
      "id": "ts7",
      "name": "TS7"
    }]

    list.sort(Sort_ID_Name);

    console.log(list);
  });

  function Sort_ID_Name(a, b) {
    try {
      var aID = a.id.toLowerCase();
      var bID = b.id.toLowerCase();
      var aName = a.name.toLowerCase();
      var bName = b.name.toLowerCase();
      return ((aID < bID) ? -1 : ((aID > bID) ? 1 : ((aName < bName) ? -1 : ((aName > bName) ? 1 : 0))));
    } catch (err) {}
  }

</script>
```

Currently the sorted list shows up like this:

```
{id: "ts1", name: "TS1"}
{id: "ts10", name: "TS10"}
{id: "ts11", name: "TS11"}
{id: "ts12", name: "TS12"}
{id: "ts13", name: "TS1"}
{id: "ts13", name: "TS2"}
{id: "ts13", name: "TS3"}
{id: "ts14", name: "TS14"}
{id: "ts15", name: "TS15"}
{id: "ts16", name: "TS16"}
....
```

The ideal state is like this

```
{id: "ts1", name: "TS1"}
{id: "ts2", name: "TS2"}
...
{id: "ts10", name: "TS10"}
{id: "ts11", name: "TS11"}
{id: "ts12", name: "TS12"}
{id: "ts13", name: "TS1"}
{id: "ts13", name: "TS2"}
{id: "ts13", name: "TS3"}
{id: "ts14", name: "TS14"}
{id: "ts15", name: "TS15"}
{id: "ts16", name: "TS16"}
....
```

The function works only when the list is very short, but when the list is long it doesn't work well. See live demo- https://jsfiddle.net/0xLd6sms/2/

Comment: How should it be sorted compared to how it is currently?

Comment: @zfrisch See live demo please. It should be sorted in order with resulting list ordered first by ID then by Name

Comment: I'm asking because it wasn't clear to me from the demo. Both the IDs and the Names are the same? Regardless for perpetuity it should be outlined within your question not externally.

Comment: @zfrisch please see updated demo, I updated the initial list

Comment: Can you post more of your code here? Some of the array of objects, etc? Posting code here shouldn't need to go elsewhere to answer.

Comment: @Matt see update

Comment: @zfrisch see update

Comment: By the way, why do you suppress all errors in `Sort_ID_Name`? That is not something I would like to see in any code. Also, are you sure you want to force your entire condition into that one-liner expression? My brain hurts.

Comment: @Mörre yes you are right i should log it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom sort method using [`localeComapre()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) specifying the  `numeric: true` option, it will smartly recognize numbers

```js
var list = [{ "id": "ts1", "name": "TS1" }, { "id": "ts10", "name": "TS10" }, { "id": "ts11", "name": "TS11" }, { "id": "ts12", "name": "TS13" }, { "id": "ts13", "name": "TS2" }, { "id": "ts13", "name": "TS1" }, { "id": "ts13", "name": "TS3" }, { "id":"ts14", "name": "TS14" }, { "id": "ts15", "name": "TS15" }, { "id": "ts16", "name": "TS16" }, { "id": "ts17", "name": "TS17" }, { "id": "ts18", "name": "TS18" }, { "id": "ts19", "name": "TS19" }, { "id": "ts2", "name": "TS2" }, { "id": "ts20", "name":"TS20" }, { "id": "ts21", "name": "TS21" }, { "id": "ts22", "name": "TS22" }, { "id": "ts3", "name": "TS3" }, { "id": "ts4", "name": "TS4" }, { "id": "ts5", "name": "TS5" }, { "id": "ts6", "name": "TS6" }, { "id": "ts7", "name": "TS7" }];
list.sort((a,b) => a.id.localeCompare(b.id, undefined, {numeric: true}) || a.name.localeCompare(b.name, undefined, {numeric: true}));
console.log(list);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I know about the options of using `{numeric: true}' but I haven't seen and can't find documentation on the undefined part. Can you explain what that does exactly or point me in the right direction? I do know it's important as it's a make-or-break deal for the code to work.

Comment: In addition to @Matt 's question, does localeCompare automatically convert to lowercase when comparing?

Comment: @user8571142 It does not do the convert from upper to lower.

Comment: Thanks, so if I want to compare only lowercase then I have to set them to lowercase first

Comment: @HassanImam can you also explain the use of `undefined` here?

Comment: The second option in `localeCompare()` is use to specify the [`locales`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl#Locale_identification_and_negotiation). For case insensitive comparison, you can add `sensitivity: 'base'` inside the 3rd argument.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing `>/<` comparisons with strings. Those work on unicode point values, which is rarely what you want. Change this:

```
  var aID = a.id.toLowerCase();
  var bID = b.id.toLowerCase();
  var aName = a.name.toLowerCase();
  var bName = b.name.toLowerCase();
```

To this:

```
  var reg = /\d+/; // matches 1 or more number characters
  var aID = +a.id.match(reg)[0]; // unary + coerces to number
  var bID = +b.id.match(reg)[0];
  var aName = +a.name.match(reg)[0];
  var bName = +b.name.match(reg)[0];
```

Now you're comparisons will be on the actual number values in the strings.